# EOS system contract is too large to execute in local machine!

Tags: smart-contract, abi

When I set the eos system contract with mainnet-v1.0.3, it always give me a error, that the transaction is too long and give me the belong error

```
{"now":"2018-06-14T08:16:44.376",
"deadline":"2018-06-14T08:16:44.369",
"start":"2018-06-14T08:16:44.339"}
```

any body can help me to solve the problem, I am get in stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by main net v1.0.3? Are you running this on your local computer as a single node test net? Or actually trying to deploy this on the main net?

Comment: @JohnWilliamson thanks, solved it in set max-transaction-time, I have test nodes in my single machine!

Comment: @KemmyGuo Happy that you found a solution. Consider writing it as an answer (you can answer your own questions on stackexchane) and mark it as the correct answer by clicking the V next to the answer. This will help future visitors with a similar question.

Comment: Awesome @KemmyGuo for future reference, 'main net' typically refers to the main network where everyone is voting at the moment. If it's just on your local computer and not connected to anything else it's not related to the main net and you can just call it a single node testnet.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid leaving this question unanswered:

OP solved their issue by increasing the `max-transaction-time` in their config file.